# VBA Variant Data with Subscript out of Range

Tags: string, excel, vba, range, variant

I'm a bit new to excel VBA and after some research I pieced together some working code (Seen at the bottom). Based off that code and a few other things I found I created this mess:

```
Sub TranslateNewBOM()


Dim NewFootPrint As Variant
Dim Translated As Variant
Dim temp As String
Dim n As Long
Dim MaxRow As Integer

Do
    MaxRow = n
    n = n + 1
Loop Until Cells(n, 3).Value = "stop"

Cells(3, 8).EntireColumn.Insert

NewFootPrint = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRow, 7)).CurrentRegion.Value
Translated = Range(Cells(3, 8), Cells(MaxRow, 8)).CurrentRegion.Value


For i = 3 To MaxRow
    temp = NewFootPrint(i, 7)  'THIS IS THE LINE THAT GIVES ME THE ERROR
    temp = Left(temp, 3)
    If temp = "" Then
        Cells(i, 5).Value = "void"
    End If
    If temp = "CAP" Then
        Translated(i, 8).Value = "SMC" & Right(NewFootPrint(i, 7).Text, _
        Len(NewFootPrint(i, 7).Text) - 3)
        Translated(i, 8) = Replace(Translated(i, 8).Text, " ", "-")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This Error doesn't make sense to me; likely because I don't fully understand Variants or Arrays in VBA. However when I compare it to the other code I made the syntax is near identical in regards to NewFootPrint. The only difference being that the numbers involved are much larger. Here the working code, it's a work in progress due to its horrible naming convention. NewFootPrint ~= DataRangeNew in my mind.

EDIT: Bottom code doesn't work anymore. I don't remember changing anything, but now the same out of range error pops up. I'm losing hair as we speak.

```
Sub GetandSortBOM()
' Data is imported through a template from a raw database.

' Variable declarations
Dim xnum As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Long
Dim Rng As Variant
Dim DataRangeNew As Variant
Dim DataRangeOld As Variant
Dim DataRangeNewFoot As Variant
Dim DataRangeNewTo As Variant
Dim DataRangeNewFootTo As Variant
Dim Irow As Long
Dim rows As Long
Dim MaxCols As Long
Dim MyVarOld As String
Dim MyVarNew As String
Dim temp() As String


DataRangeNew = Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(1587, 12)).CurrentRegion.Value         ' These work together
DataRangeNewFoot = Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(1587, 13)).CurrentRegion.Value     ' and store data in
DataRangeOld = Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(MaxRows, 3)).CurrentRegion.Value        ' columns without cell
DataRangeNewTo = Range(Cells(3, 8), Cells(MaxRows, 8)).CurrentRegion.Value      ' manipulation. Too much
DataRangeNewFootTo = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRows, 7)).CurrentRegion.Value  ' data to go through without
Rng = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRows, 8)).CurrentRegion.Value
NumRows = Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(1587, 12)).CurrentRegion.rows.Count


For rows = 3 To MaxRows
    MyVarOld = DataRangeOld(rows, 3)
    For Irow = 1 To NumRows
                                         ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        MyVarNew = DataRangeNew(Irow, 12)' Why does this work, but not my other code? '
                                         ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        If MyVarOld = MyVarNew Then
            DataRangeNewTo(rows, 8) = DataRangeOld(rows, 3)
            DataRangeNewFootTo(rows, 7) = DataRangeNewFoot(Irow, 13)
        End If
    Next Irow
Next rows

' Combines 2 columns of new data into a 2D array
ReDim temp(1 To MaxRows, 1 To 2)

' Puts the information into the 2D array
For i = 3 To MaxRows
    Rng(i, 7) = DataRangeNewFootTo(i, 7)
    Rng(i, 8) = DataRangeNewTo(i, 8)
Next i

' Puts 2D array in cells
Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRows, 7)).CurrentRegion = Rng


End Sub
```

The error is a Runtime Error '9': Subcript out of range.
To me it seems that it's actually in the range; at least when you compare to my old code. 
Help?

Comment: Did you check what is **MaxRow**'s value?  try debug.print / msgbox before the line of error

Comment: Since you use CurrentRegion, NewFootPrint and Translated probably contain the same values. Is that your intent ? And are you sure that array has 7 columns ?

Comment: **MaxRow**'s value is correct, but when debugging it errors at the first occurrence. So **i** or **7** causes the error.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding how I declared my Variants. I want it to contain the data in a column.

For example: NewFootPrint should contain the cells from Row3Col7 to Row(MaxRows)Col7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case:

```
NewFootPrint = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRow, 7)).CurrentRegion.Value
```

will *not* create an array with 7 columns, because it's a single column. :-) So, trying to index it like `NewFootPrint(i, 7)` won't work. You should initialize your `Variant` like this:

```
NewFootPrint = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRow, 7)).Value
```

or, even better:

```
With Worksheets("whatever worksheet use")
    ' ...
    NewFootPrint = .Range(.Cells(3, 7), .Cells(MaxRow, 7)).Value
    ' ...
End With
```

and access it like this:

```
NewFootPrint(i, 1)
```

**Later edit:**
Getting the data in a range from (r1, c1) to (r2, c2), where r2 ≥ r1 and c2 ≥ c1, will create an array (1 To r2-r1+1, 1 To c2-c1+1). So you should check *all* your for loops and *all* your indices.

Answer (score 0):

- Since you use `CurrentRegion`, NewFootPrint and Translated probably contain the same values. Is that your intent ? Otherwise, remove that `CurrentRegion`
- And are you sure that array has 7 columns ?
- Also `For rows = 3 To MaxRows` should probably be `For rows = 0 To MaxRows - 4`
  since such an array is zero based.
- You could also `Dim NewFootPrint as Range` and then
  `Set NewFootPrint = Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(MaxRow, 7))`

Comment: Thanks, I found this helpful. As so as I  get the rep. I'll up vote.